# Filter File based on directory

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have directory which contain multiple sub directory and each sub directory also contain
 multiple directory.I have file which present in all sub directory and need to pick file based on sub directory.Can I get some input.

```
like  <cell 1> <cell 2> <cell 3>
each cell1
     <job 1> <job 2> < job 3>
each job contain sample. txt
```

similar cell2 and cell 3. So I want to extract sample.txt from each cell/job1 directory.
and written following program.
**just modify program after fix issue . Can we done more better way**

```
#!/usr/bin/py
import os
def find_all(name, path):
    result = []
    for root, dir, files in os.walk(path):
        print "root %s dir %s" %(root, dir)
        if "job1" in root:
            print "\n"
            if name in files:
                result.append(os.path.join(root, name))
    return result
name = "sample.txt"
path = "."
data = find_all(name, path)
print data
```

~

Comment: import os; from glob import glob; for f in glob("./cell*/job*/sample.txt"): if os.path.dirname(f).endswith("job1"): whatever()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second element of yielded tuple (by os.walk) is list of directory, not a directory name.

And you should check `root` instead of `dirs`.

Try following:

```
def find_all(name, path):
    result = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        if os.path.basename(root) == 'job1':
            if name in files:
                result.append(os.path.join(root, name))
    return result
```

An alternative that use [`glob.glob`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.glob):

```
import glob
import os

data = glob.glob(os.path.join('cell*', 'job1', 'sample.txt'))
```

Comment: it will return all file but I am looking for file in specific folder